# get protected attribute by parameter referencing name?

Tags: php, object, protected

lets say:

```
class myclass{
     protected $info;
     protected $owner;
     __construct(){
        $this->info = 'nothing';
        $this->owner = 'nobody';
    }
    function getProp($string){
        return $this->$string;
    }
}
```

But its not working, is it not posible? its not returning anything or showing errors

Comment: Works for me (after fixing your `_construct` declaration. Was missing `function` keyword).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, but you're missing the function keyword in front of `__construct`.  This outputs "nothing":

```
<?php

class myclass{
     protected $info;
     protected $owner;

    function __construct(){
        $this->info = 'nothing';
        $this->owner = 'nobody';
    }
    function getProp($string){
        return $this->$string;
    }
}

$test = new myclass();
echo $test->getProp('info');
```

Comment: Haha yeah, almost the same time too.  Funny that I chose to put backticks around `__construct` and you chose to put them around `function`.

Answer (score 1):

I added the `function` before your __construct, but other than that it seems to work fine

```
class myclass{
     protected $info;
     protected $owner;
     function __construct(){
        $this->info = 'nothing';
        $this->owner = 'nobody';
     }
     function getProp($string){
        return $this->$string;
     }
}

$m = new myclass();
echo $m->getProp('info');

// echos 'nothing'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read up on PHP's magic methods. What you're doing is very possible, but the way you're doing it is perhaps not the best.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

I think you should be looking at the __get() and __set() methods.